# How to change ALT+TAB to CONTROL

Tags: autohotkey

I do a lot of switching between apps and I'd like to know if there is a way to do that using Autohotkey.
is there a script for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/) -

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1.33

!Tab::Return         ; disables default ALT + TAB
LControl::AltTabMenu ; Show or hide the ALT + TAB menu when Left Control is pressed

; press Left Control + CapsLock to toggle On/Off the script
; so that you can use the control key for normal functionality when required
LControl & CapsLock::Suspend, toggle
```

Create a script with the above code, or
include this in the an existing script. (Warning: `Suspend` command will disable all other hotkeys and hotstrings in an existing script)

Comment: In AHK1 this compiles but doesnt work, in AHK2 it errors on load

Comment: @Adeerlike The code has been updated. Should work now. I don't compile my scripts. not sure if I can help you with that. Let me know if you still face errors.